# How can I access vue project which is running by npm run server command from any other computer or mobile that is connected in the same network?

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I am running a *VueJS* project in *Ubuntu* v18.04.

When I run the project using `npm run serve`, it works fine and I can  …
- access it in my Local: *http://localhost:8080/*.
- also access it using Network: *http://myip:8080/*.

But I cannot access it from any other computer (or via mobile) despite the fact that devices are on the same network.

Adding the host in *vue.config.js* file doesn't has no effect and running the command `npm run serve --host 0.0.0.0` only result in the following error:

```
/var/www/html/unilliver_vue/0.0.0.0 in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.53.75:8080/sockjs-node
(webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./0.0.0.0, multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost
(webpack)/hot/dev-server.js (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.53.75:8080/sockjs-node ./0.0.0.0
```

To install it, you can run: `npm install --save`

```
/var/www/html/unilliver_vue/0.0.0.0
```

Here is the code of vue.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
   dev: {
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/koreyomo/',
    proxyTable: {},
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080, 
    autoOpenBrowser: false,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
  },
}
```

I am using `vuecli 3`, node version `10.16.3` and `npm version 6.9.0`. Can anyone suggest me what to do if I want to access from other devices?

Answer (score 0):

**All you need to do is make sure your laptop and mobile are on the same Wifi Connection**

**Just Run** `npm run serve`

Network: http://192.168.1.***:8100/

Type that network address in your mobile browser

*It works for create-react-app & vue-cli*

**Hot reload will also work**

*If you don't have WiFi use a mobile hotspot*